# digital compass problem

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am creating an augmented reality application and I noticed that the stored locations don't appear appear on the correct direction if I try to use the camera view (using layar or wikitude API).
The problem is that the digital compass doesn't show north correctly when you try to look at the known objects through the camera view. If align the phone with the ground (look at my shoes) the locations appear at the screen according to heading rotation.

So I guess the compass should be aligned with roll when used in portrait mode or with pitch in landscape mode.

Anyway I would be thankful if anyone of you could share the possible solution for the described issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did once see that problem on my G1, but it went away. You may need to re-calibrate your compass. To do that, you "wave your phone in a figure-8" (yeah, I'm not completely sure what they mean by that either). I guess you should just pretend it's a magic wand and you should try to cast a spell on something on the other side of your room.

But practically, I think the phone needs to see the magnetometer values while it's in a number of different orientations, so just turn it in all kinds of directions.

Comment: Is that like doing a 8 (infinity) loop like in the original Descent? :P That was a real finger twister